# Add a Filter to SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, filter, ssrs-2008

I need to add a filter to a Report, that within anotherreport, the filtered results appear in the drilldown  report. 
For example: An .rdl file displays the first report, in that report a  link can be clicked to access another report (.rdl) file. The report that displays after clicking link should be filtered by option selected from the first report(.rdl). 
How could this be done? My thought that two datasets in each report could provide the information for the filter, however the filter expression is not valid this way...? I know this may not be the best way to do this.

So creating a drilldown report would be more acceptable. Creating one report and including a dataset with it by setting parameters to be called in the drilldown.

Does there need to be two datasets for each report to do this? I was assuming that the filter expression be written to do this: Field!.name.value AND Field!.name.value, etc to the whatever value I need to compare to or by.

Could this be a shared dataset to do this?

Comment: Why do you think you need two datasets?  It makes me think I don't understand your question.   Can you give a more detailed example of what you want to happen?

Comment: Can't you pass the filtered results into the second reports parameter. Example you have a parameters which is a multivalue dropdown of values in report 1, the parameter is then passed into a parameter in report2. Once passed in you can do whatever you want with it in report 2. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Creating a dropdown of values works okay in "report 1", however, when I try to create the filter in the "report 2", it does not seem to work. The following error occurs: "Unknown Collection Member" for =First(Fields!____.Value, dataset).

Comment: To be more exact, what I want to do is have the report 2 "trickle down" or pass the data from report 1 with filtered results and display that data in report 2. Report 1 would contain the option for report 2 for how that data that needs to be excluded or included(filtered).

Comment: I thought with two datasets that a comparison could be made between those datasets on separate reports to filter that report and what I need to have it display, much like a shared dataset, in the scenario where I cannot use a shared dataset for instance.

Comment: I suppose is this possible with two datasets to add filters to both reports and have it display final result in the second report that does not have the dropdown?

Comment: Passing the parameter works. However, can a filter be done using this parameter that is created in the drillthrough report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve or partially solve this. I created a new report, with a query with the necessary columns that I needed in report 2. The drillthrough report(report 2) is linked from a textbox from a report allowing a user to view the information they need by clicking a link that displays the new report(passing the parameters from report 2 to the new report). If anyone has trouble with this, the simplest way would be to create one report and pass parameters to report two with parameters created from whatever query you want to use that has the values you want as columns in the report.